An example of a groupoid that satisfy the following hypothesis
In the paper titled, 'Tannaka–Krein duality for compact groupoids I, Representation theory',  the author proves the Peter Weyl theorem on compact groupoids. In the statement, he gives the hypothesis that $\lambda_{u}(G^{v}_{u})\neq 0$, where $\lambda_{u}$ is the right haarsystem with support in $G_{u},u\in G^{0}$.
Here, $G^{v}_{u} = G^{v}\cap G_{u}$ with $G_{u}= d^{-1}(u)$ and $G^{v}= r^{-1}(v)$ , where $d$ and $r$ are domain and range maps respectively from groupoid $G$ to unit space $G^{0}$, defined as $d(x)=x^{-1}x$ and $r(x)=xx^{-1}$.
Is there any example of a compact groupoid that satisfies this hypothesis?
Please see the following link to see the Peter Weyl theorem statement
![1]: https://i.sstatic.net/KPCtX2vG.png
In this paper, $X$, is the unit space $G^{0}$.

Please do not (mimicking your imperative mood) phrase the title (and a sentence in the content) in imperative mood. MO users are not supposed to execute your orders.
